# How to limit size of GeometryReader inside a VStack

Tags: swiftui, vstack, geometryreader

I would like to stop `GeometryReader` from interfering with my layout in a `VStack` but I'm not sure what the correct approach is.

Given the example of a simple graph with a title and caption:

```
struct Graph: View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
      Color.red.frame(width: 100, height: 80)
      Color.blue.frame(width: 100, height: 120)
      Color.green.frame(width: 100, height: 180)
    }
  }
}

struct GraphExample: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {

      Text("My graph")

      // Graph represents a custom view with a natural and non-static height
      Graph()

      Text("My graph caption")
    }
  }
}
```

Produces this expected result:

[image]

But if we update the `Graph` view to use a `GeometryReader` to evenly split the graph across the width of the screen the layout changes.

```
struct Graph: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
      HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.red.frame(width: proxy.size.width / 3, height: 80)
        Color.blue.frame(width: proxy.size.width / 3, height: 120)
        Color.green.frame(width: proxy.size.width / 3, height: 180)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This makes the `Graph` view fill all available space in `VStack`

[image]

Is there a way to allow `Graph` view to just fill its natural height up, and not consume all available height while still using the `GeometryReader`.

Bear in mind that `Graph` could be any view here where the exact size is not known, so setting a static size is not possible. i.e. without `GeometryReader`, `Graph` can takes up only the needed amount of vertical space in the VStack.

Comment: Do you want to make a bar chart? that takes dynamic bar height based on the data value?

Comment: `GeometryReader` is greedy with respect to layout - it always attempts to maximize its frame inside of the context of its parent. In this case, I recommend simply adding horizontal padding to your geometry reader to define a distance from the edges of the screen. e.g. `.padding(.horizontal, 20)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image]

```
struct Graph: View {
  @State private var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width // just initial constant
  var body: some View {
      HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.red.frame(width: width / 3, height: 80)
        Color.blue.frame(width: width / 3, height: 120)
        Color.green.frame(width: width / 3, height: 180)
      }.background(GeometryReader { gp -> Color in
        let frame = gp.frame(in: .local)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.width = frame.size.width // << dynamic, on layout !!
        }
        return Color.clear
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a crazy trick probably leading to layout loops. Especially the `DispatchQueue.main.async` part.